# Entity Framework with MySQL throwing exception when deployed to a hosted environment

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have deployed an ASP.NET application which uses:
.NET 4,5
Entity Framework 6.1.3
MySql.Data 6.9.8
MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.8

It works correctly in my development environment.

I am getting the following error message when access the database.

> The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'
>   threw an exception.
>
> System.Security.SecurityException:
>   System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission  at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory..cctor()
>
> The type of the first permission that failed was:
>   System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
>
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

If I access the hosted MySQL database from an IIS server on my local computer everything works correctly.

I have tried/checked:

- ensuring that the DLLs have CopyLocal set to true
- Adding a `trust level` setting to web.config; this caused the application to fail on the hosted server
- I have the latest version of the MySQL DLLs
- Used Google
- Raised it as a support issue with the hosting company and searched their FAQs

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to let people know which hosting provider you are using - they could have experienced similar issues themselves.

Some hosting providers are picky about particular config settings, for example Trust Settings as you mentioned.

Some hosting providers also provide quick assistance to their customers - this could be an issue that a lot of their new customers face, and if so they could cover how to resolve this in a FAQ/Help section. If this isn't covered in a FAQ/Help section then customer support may be able to provide assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have already raised with the hosting company and am waiting their response

Answer (score 0):

I got a standard response from the hosting company. The solution seems to be to use the DLLs from the GAC. However, as using MySQL was problematic for several reasons, I switched to using an Azure SQL server. It's a very light application so the costs was very low. I will return to the MySQL solution when I have some spare time - and share anything I find here.